# Strange found error in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am having a strange issue with codeigniter. I'm trying to check the email in a registration form so that they can't enter the same email in the database and I'm getting a found error when I try to redirect to an error page. This has honestly driven me crazy...and it's probably something really simple. Help, please.

here is the code I'm working on, in my model

```
public function checkEmail(){
        $idCheck = $this->db->query('Select email from user_tbl Where email  ="'.$_POST["email"].'"');

        if($idCheck->num_rows() > 0)
        {   
            redirect('home/errorPage');
        }else{
            redirect('home/');
        }   
    }
```

0 Found The document has moved here. Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 10 May 2013 01:18:37 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 1653 Connection: keep-alive Server: Nginx / Varnish X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13

Comment: this is the error...it wouldnt let me post it above

   0

   Found

   The document has moved here.

   Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 10 May 2013 01:18:37 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 1653 Connection: keep-alive Server: Nginx / Varnish X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13

Comment: When does the error happen? When the email exists? or when it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter redirect function is written in the url helper class.

check once, whether you have loaded the url helper class or not. OR check whether the redirect function is exists or not by

```
var_dump(function_exists('redirect'));exit;
```

and if it comes out to be false then add the below line, to load the url helper.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

and try once by passing the complete url for the redirect in the redirect function, or by adding a slash in front of "home" to "/home"

About redirect functions:-

The redirect function loads a local URI specified in the first parameter of the function call and built using the options specified in your config file.

The second parameter allows the developer to use different HTTP commands to perform the redirect "location" or "refresh".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The url helper was loading correctly, but it seems that codeigniter really wanted that refreash after the redirect.

    redirect('/home/errorPage', 'refresh');

Answer (score 0):

**Out of topic**

`Codeigniter` has a built in `validation` for checking unique entries on your database `is_unique` use it like `is_unique[table.field]`

docs : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference

And one last thing, you may want to escape your `post` variables by using

`query binding` : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

produces much safer queries.